# Error Code 500 on Embedded Glassfish 4.1.1 with Arquillian

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jboss-arquillian

I am quite new to Java EE and Arquillian. I am getting problems if I want to deploy my simple project into the embedded glassfish 4.1.1 server. I can succesfully pass the deployment, but I can not access the methods that i implemented. I am getting error code 500, while i expect 200.

my deployment:

```
public class AuthTest
{
    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static WebArchive createDeployment()
    {
        System.out.println("\nin createDeployment");
//        File[] libs = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeAndTestDependencies().asFile();
        WebArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "ArquillianHepInterface.war")
                .addClasses(AuthEndpoint.class)
                .addPackage(Database.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(DeviceAccessDBEntry.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(WebsiteAccessDBEntry.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(DeviceInfo.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(LoginInfo.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(ResponseBoolean.class.getPackage())
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(new File("src/main/webapp", "WEB-INF/web.xml"))
                .addAsWebInfResource(new File("src/main/webapp", "WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml"))
                .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")
//              .addAsLibraries(libs)
                ;
        System.out.println("\nende createDeployment");
        return archive;
    }

    @ArquillianResource
    protected URL contextPath;

    @Test
    public void registerUUIDTest()
    {
        DeviceInfo newUser = new DeviceInfo();
        newUser.setDate("2014-12-12");
        newUser.setUuid("xyz");
        Response i = expect().statusCode(200).when().given().
        contentType("application/json").body(newUser)
        .post(this.contextPath + "AUTHENTICATION/CREATEMOBILELOGIN")
        ;
    }
```

my AuthEndpoint class:

```
@Path("/AUTHENTICATION")
public class AuthEndpoint
{
    @Inject
    private DatabaseInterface database;

    @POST
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    @Consumes({ "application/json" })
    @Path("CREATEMOBILELOGIN")
    public LoginInfo createMobileLogin(DeviceInfo info)
    {
        System.out.println("RICHTIGES FILE");
        System.err.println();
        LoginInfo response = null;
        if (info != null && info.getUuid() != null)
        {
            String password = this.database.registerDevice(info.getUuid());
            if (password != null)
            {
                response = new LoginInfo();
                response.setPw(password);
                response.setUuid(info.getUuid());
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

I am getting:
SEVERE: WebModule[/ArquillianHepInterface]StandardWrapper.Throwable

Why is that happening? I do not understand where my problem is...
I supposed that I have problems while I am using glassfish 4.1.1...? I want simply to call the Methods in the AuthEndpoint class throught the Arquillian TestClass to verify that a single have been created...

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Arquillian Rest Demo</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>REST-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>REST-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

glassfish-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
    <glassfish-web-app>
        <context-root>/ArquillianHepInterface</context-root>
        <class-loader delegate="true" />
    </glassfish-web-app>
```

My beans.xml file is empty.

The methods that AuthEndpoint uses are in another maven project that I have compiled and added in the maven dependencies...
I would appreciate any help...

Comment: Could add the full stack trace of the exception please?